# prove that $H \in \mathcal F$

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

let $f$, $g$  injective functions

$f:E\rightarrow F$ and $g:F\rightarrow E$

consider this set defined as follow

$\mathcal F=\left\{C\subset E,  g\left(F-f(C)\right)\subseteq E-C\right\}$

i have proved that $\mathcal F$ is non empty

let

$ K=\bigcup\limits_{ C \in \mathcal F}C$ and $H= E-g(F-f(K))$

i have proved that $K \subseteq H$

and if $y \in F-f(H) $ then $g(y)$ not in $H$

how we can deduce that $H \in \mathcal F$

please help me with this question

Comment: Just chase the definition of what $H\in\mathcal{F}$ means.